# A result in group theory about subgroups that are normalised and Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.

> Let $A, B \le G$ and suppose that $p$ is prime and divides the order of $G$. Let $g \in G$ and suppose
>   $$
>  \langle (A^g)^b : b \in B \rangle 
> $$
>   is a $p$-group. Then there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ such that
>   $$
>  \langle A^x : x \in G, A^x \le S \rangle
> $$
>   is normalized by $B$.

Who originated this result, has it a name? And where can I find information about it?

Comment: The element $g$ does not appear to be playing any role. Why not just replace $A$ by $A^g$ and eliminate $g$? What makes you believe this result is true?

Comment: Yes, I see. It is from handwritten lecture notes, I think it is possible that there are some typos in the statement. But does it remind you of anything, maybe a slight hint that I know for what I can look for... in the lecture notes there also appears a name like "Matsugard", but it is very difficult to read, so it might mean anything else, just like that it starts with "M$ I am sure of...

Comment: I was interpreting the assumption as $\langle (A^g)^b : b \in B \rangle$ is a $p$-group for some $g \in G$, and I think that the result is wrong under that assumption (I have a counterexample). But I suppose that it is possible that the assumption is $\langle (A^g)^b : b \in B \rangle$ is a $p$-group for all $g \in G$, which is a much stronger assumption.

Comment: This assumption should guarantee that we could find a $p$-subgroup of $G$ which is generated by conjugates of $A$ and which is $B$-invariant, so it might be supposed for all $g \in G$. Sorry that I could not give more precise information, as I am deciphering it too from these handwritte lecture notes...